# Convert 3D Array to JSON and save it in a FILE (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How can I save my 3D array into a JSON file in JavaScript? And how can I read the JSON and convert it back to a 3D array?

The array is in the format of `[x][y][k]`.
I am using this array to map a chess board, which x,y are the coordinates and k is 0 or 1 or 2 which stands for the color.

The array looks like this: `[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,2,1],[0,3,2],...,[18,18,0]`.

The array is initialized in the following manner:

```
var chessBoard = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    chessBoard[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        chessBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

I expect this array to be saved whenever I press a button. How can this be done?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of the input format? If it's a Javascript object, you can just `JSON.stringify` it.

Comment: If it's an array, then the response is the same, just JSON.stringify to turn an array into a string

Comment: But can i save JSON as a FILE in plain javascript? Btw, the array is in `[x][y][k]` not `[x,y,k]`. @CertainPerformance

Comment: But that contradicts what you said in your question...

Comment: Which part? Isn't [x][y][k] the 3D array syntax?

Comment: There's not really any such thing as "3d array" in Javascript - there are only single-dimensional arrays that can reference other single-dimensional arrays. Also, `[x][y][z]` is invalid syntax without an object in front of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168156/discussion-between-eric-hua-and-certainperformance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chessBoard` is an object, so it can certainly be serialized and downloaded easily:

```js
const chessBoard = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  chessBoard[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
    chessBoard[i][j] = 0;
  }
}

download(JSON.stringify(chessBoard), 'chessboard.json', 'application/json');

function download(content, name, type) {
  const a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('a'));
  const file = new Blob([content], {
    type: type
  });
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
  a.click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify ()` to convert an array into a JSON data string, and you can use `JSON.parse ()` to convert a JSON data string back into an actual array.

Like this...

```
/* YOUR CODE */
var chessBoard = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    chessBoard[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
        chessBoard[i][j] = 0;
    }
}

// Convert array into JSON data string
var chessJSON = JSON.stringify (chessBoard);

// Convert JSON data string back into array
var chessBoard = JSON.parse (chessJSON);
```

You cannot, however, write the JSON data to a file in normal JavaScript. You can in Node.js and other server-side JavaScript, but not JavaScript in the browser. If the JavaScript is running in the browser you will need to send the data to a server-side program, or offer the user a download link for the data.

Comment: Can I do it in vuejs?

Comment: Yes. I don't know of a single framework that restricts usage of standard JavaScript. However, you would need to post the actual section of code that contains the array you need to convert into JSON for us to help you in more detail.

Comment: And the array is in `[x][y][k]` but not `[x, y, k]`.

Comment: Thanks, but your update isn't enough info. Where is the array stored, where does it come from, and where do you expect to convert the array to JSON? For example, is your code in a callback, a function, or in the global namespace?

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
    chressBord[i] = [];
    chessOrder[i] = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < 15; j++){
      chressBord[i][j] = 0;
      chessOrder[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to show the basic usage of `JSON.stringify ()` and `JSON.parse ()`.